# selfintersection of curves inside 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

What are all the possibilities of the self intersection number of a smooth curve inside an Enriques surface?

Comment: The adjunction formula for an irreducible curve $D$ on a Enriques surface reads $p_a(D)=\frac{D^2}2+1$. Hence you can probably show that $D^2$ can take every even number $\ge -2$.

Comment: @Ottem: Thanks. Please correct me if I am wrong. Adjunction formula says $K_D=K_X.D \|D + D.D$, if $K_X$ is trivial then your formula is correct. But for Enrique surface $K_X$ is not trivial.

Comment: For an Enriques surface $K_X$ is indeed not trivial, but $2K_X \sim 0$, and that's good enough: $K_X\cdot D$ takes integer values, so $2 (K_X \cdot D) = (2K_X \cdot D) = 0$ implies $K_X \cdot D = 0$.